# Widening behaviour when using typeof

Tags: typescript, typeof

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of TypeScript when widening certain literal types. I have created a code example to explain: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogRwK4CGANgDTYAeqAxvAL5wBmUEIcA5AAJKoC0VAFsSIoAdgHMUAZwD0eGMCKS2AWABQa0XlYBlQakkY1cONvwEoaALztJZi2xJG4AJRQ0C44XGtsL7zygqqrRqasLwAILecACMANxhKPAAQtFsAEZEBPxsCarhcADC0TBQeCh5BQAi0boE+gB0rv5iwnlq3GgwUjAG1gDaTliUbjAAPLiERGOdEAxwEWQiWukoUAB8646qxsPU45PEM8goc3DJZJKlwOKb27sjNBNm07PzhWTpEBDCHndDjwOL2OqDOVTIdX0mzUAF0gA).

I have 4 examples of literal types that I assign to let variables:

```
let A = 1;
let B = 'blah';
let C = true;
let D = Shapes.Rectangle;
```

If you hover over each `let` in the playground you can see that the literal type has been widened to its broader type as expected for all four types. However, when combined with `typeof` in the tests, only `A` and `B` widen to their broader types whereas `C` and `D` do not.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript compiler needs to statically decide the type of variable
that should not change throughout the program.

Hence when it is not sure of the exact type it defaults to the closest wider type that it can resolve to.

As `let` declaration can change somewhere in our execution down the line,
it makes a pragmatic guess and assigns its type of `number`
The same happens with `boolean`, `string`, and other `enum` types

With `let` is possible that somewhere else we can reassign D as Shapes.Square
So in that case we don't want our types to be out of sync and behave randomly!

But if we make it const, we are guaranteed that they won't change throughout the execution of this program
Hence it is safe for the typescript compiler to infer the literal assigned type

In case you want the types to be the actual types and not the widened ones, you can always annotate it so!
`let D: Shapes.Rectangle = Shapes.Rectangle`

```
import type { Equal, Expect } from '@type-challenges/utils'

enum Shapes {
  Square = 'square',
  Rectangle = 'rectangle'
}

const A = 1; 
const B = 'blah';
const C = true;
const D = Shapes.Rectangle;

type tests = [
  Expect<Equal<typeof A, 1>>,
  Expect<Equal<typeof B, 'blah'>>,
  Expect<Equal<typeof C, true>>,
  Expect<Equal<typeof D, Shapes.Rectangle>>
]
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogRwK4CGANgDTYAeqAxvAL5wBmUEIcA5AAJKoC0VAFsSIoAdgHMUAZwD0eGMCKS2AWABQa0XlYBlQakkY1cONvwEoaALztJZi2xJG4AJRQ0C44XGtsL7zygqqrRqatIAVHAAKshSVFDAYPBULGAKKFBwIigoACYGMBBwkjAE8lRCiHC5bsA1CPxo3GgQDHAAbubABABGXmowgvCS-BB4RLlZEMmC4k38zHhi-HBj8INoYMxiUAQgagASolRoAO6NInDA8MAGItPFeBarbRtwKOQENAixV-A1DAI4xgBSKbyoRAgkik8FOdQyP1QcHOwAEfzgFUuFkkECI7SaRVCqgAggZhP83ERzGVgBBLpiMbMJMUWChzhk0MBLmNMh83HJaZcudUIKdLm8iFyUI5VNc4CACABrKRwAhwLYEMR7cpwMR4KQGDyTAiSSTAMQiAxy5ovOAAAxEWh6GTtam0ezQelQluR1xWPQguJQHjIJQS4lVIkm00avMdrGakiJABlgMr0bd1VCzX15mUWSA2bG0ChFGc0AyLCazRa4AARVUGXQEfQAOlMhAsbqKwsG%20Yq0ORaFydLYsI88B5iJVhTgztWcltkkQIiokcmzsE%20LguyjLCIiAAhESAEKL4BtU5oBXpuUpS0wMhX1XPPXUkQwHKTPvrRpVU6jjMHjMoMizLGsDQluQ-LyHStqDJmWwQDseyHMcnI3AYkgEAwaAMNA06SPEiTJKk6SZLOXK4RRjRwJKn67EQjY1tk36-Go4TSES0jSHAADCTJ5IwzCsOSCBFPeJRwESknwMS3hwAAjAA3NJqiyXAJ4KWwfQEPwbDKWoGl8QpMBQPqhnqXSUkNtYzZtq4-hiMIlkDL8n4lAY1gANpOFglBuDAAA8uCEEQQXNK0cDEmQikAHxxTKxj%20dQwWhcQEWxFFJ5kDpVL6QlSUUKlIVmOFkVtHxZBmfqhV%20QFNClWFmWoFFdZkPZUito5pQBAlagALpAA)

Now coming towards your question that why Typescript narrows some of the types (`boolean`, `Enum`), whereas widens the other ones (`number`, `string`)

The simple reason for that is Typescript compiler is smart enough to check that if the Type set contains `finite` type elements then it can infer it based on the usage.

Ex 1: `type boolean = true | false` // finite set

Ex 2:  `enum Shapes { Square = 'square', Rectangle = 'rectangle'}` // finite set

Here we defined `FiniteTypes` alias which constitutes of `number | string | any[]`
Hence when we reassign values to any of these types, `typeof` is sure of the type that is currently in the variable as it can loop over the constituents

Whereas in the case of types which are `number`, `string`, etc there are infinite constituents for these and hence we don't narrow down the type based on its reassignment.

Example

```
// Proof that TS compiler is smart enough to loop through Finite elements of type

type FiniteTypes = number | string | any[]

let z: FiniteTypes = 2
type t_1 = typeof z // Inferred as number

z = [1,2,3]
type t_2 = typeof z // Inferred as any[]

z = "Foo bar"
type t_3 = typeof z // Inferred as string
```

[Example for narrowing types based on Assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAogRwK4CGANgDTYAeqAxvAL5wBmUEIcA5AAJKoC0VAFsSIoAdgHMUAZwD0eGMCKS2AWABQa0XlYBlQakkY1cONvwEoaALztJZi2xJG4AJRQ0C44XGtsL7zygqqrRqatxoAGLAIsAwKAAqyFLecCJaAEYoUHAAPnCSMFDRYrlwHogA2gC6oarC8ACCKQCMpQBMANxq9XAAQils6UQE-GxddSjwAMIAXHDpEBDCHnDjPQAiKboE%20gB0rv5iwuO10tJwAArMEAwIgvDx2nBULGAKWXDABpIg5vCiEDwYn4CAgcCIizAd2YQJBURicTgKGEIFEMAMNwQSVqPQAXnN4bEEkkDNY2mEkggAPqtazhTG4uBnOAASREDCyFgAJmUDGkQJkoLVGdYKs0SG0SABmGqqcLUtopem3RnMtkcqDc3llESVWVqEVwABEEUW83MRopqGpUqVSQZTPO6s5KB5BG%20hWKtTUQA)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question. I'm aware we can use const to prevent the widening from happening. The question is around why using `typeof` on each of the let's has different behaviour in terms of widening.

Comment: It does answer the question although your original assessment of what the playground shows is actually with regards to the `Equal` generic, which appears to function incorrectly when its a `let` (reporting false when it is typeof boolean).  If you `console.log(typeof C)` you'll see that the reported type is in fact widened as per A and B.

Comment: Hmm ok that's interesting, I see the behaviour with the console.log. But if you then look at this amended [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygFgQwA7AM5QN4FgBQVYCOYCATsFALxQDkqRpw1ANLvgErADGALgiAOYAbclWpkefIY1wBfXLmHcoAQUpQAjAG4FwJQCE11AEaCEcatpyKoAYTXcSYYJesARNfGRoAdBwkDhS1xuAE8UFXV7MOAAewAzFUtQ8L1IqmTYhL0k6Ns0qAz42xzw13zChNdNIA) you can see that when you hover over `A1` and `B1` the inferred type has widened as expected but when hovering over `C1` and `D2` it has not. Still a bit puzzled.

Comment: @yonatanhakatan I have added more explanation to clear out the question about the different behavior of `typeof` operators based on different types.
Mark, it is accepted, and upvote it, if that answers your question, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. The comment about the "finite set" makes sense and coupled with this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48696#issuecomment-1101957019) explains the behaviour. Have accepted/upvoted your answer.